# Grouping by week/month/etc & ActiveRecord?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, grouping

I'm doing some statics calculation in my product.  A user has performed a number of operations, let's say posted comments.  I want to be able to show them how many comments they've posted per week for the past month, or per month for the past year.

Is there any way with activerecord to group this way?  Is my best best to simply do this manually - to iterate over the records summing based on my own criteria?

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments
end

class Comments < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end

@user.comments(:all).map {|c| ...do my calculations here...}
```

or is there some better way?

thanks!
Oren

Answer (score 32, accepted):

In this case, the best solution for me was to either do it in straight SQL, or to use the Ruby group_by function:

```
@user.all.group_by{ |u| u.created_at.beginning_of_month }
```

Comment: `group_by` is not an ActiveRecord method, but rather a Ruby method on `Enumerable`.

Comment: Just using `u.created_at.month` is shorter

Comment: Please not that this will load all records from the database, instantiate ActiveRecord objects, parse dates into ActiveSupport's time zone aware objects – all just to calculate number of records.

Comment: This is a bad practice because when you use .all it get all records in database which will cost you too much

Comment: Better way is to use database group function

Comment: Unless you have "smallish" set of objects then this method will not treat you well; ram usage of our server reached 1.3GB because of our usage of `#group_by`, as said by an earlier comment, this will instantiate so many Ruby objects that it'll clog your server.

Comment: What a waste of memory! Use @WojtekKruszewski solution: `@user.comments.group("DATE_TRUNC('month', created_at)").count`

Comment: Adding case when `group_by` is required & want to instantiate AR objects. When dealing with different currencies, you can't simply DB level group & sum amount columns.

Answer (score 96):

In Postgres you can do:

```
@user.comments.group("DATE_TRUNC('month', created_at)").count
```

to get:

```
{"2012-08-01 00:00:00"=>152, "2012-07-01 00:00:00"=>57, "2012-09-01 00:00:00"=>132}
```

It accepts values from "microseconds" to "millennium" for grouping:
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TRUNC

Comment: So much faster than using ruby enumerable group_by!

Comment: Wojtek, what about when there was nothing created in a month? You don't get anything for that month.

Comment: @MattSmith I believe so. Fortunately it's easy to provide default value when reading values from the output of this query: ```output.fetch("2012-08-01 00:00:00", 0)```

Comment: In my case, the keys are Ruby Time objects, so I can access the result with `result[Time.current.utc.beginning_of_month]`. Not sure why the answer shows the result with String keys, or if that's changed over the years.

Comment: Is there a sort? lol the keys are out of order

Answer (score 27):

Here is the more refined version of this

```
@user.comments.group("year(created_at)").group("month(created_at)").count
```

Also

```
@user.comments.group("year(created_at)", "month(created_at)").count
```

Answer (score 14):

My guess would be something like:

```
@user.comments.count(:group => "year(created_at),month(created_at)")
```

Dry-code, ymmv

Comment: I believe this will group by month across years as well - so if you've got two years of data, all stuff in January year 1 and year 2.  What I'm looking for is a way of telling for a 24 month window for example, how many per month.

Comment: You could add a condition to limit the year also, like :conditions => [:created_at, "> #{24.months.ago}"]. Again, untested, but should be possible with something like this.

Comment: This seems mysql specific

Answer (score 4):

Use group_by

```
@user.comments.group_by(&:week)

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def week
    some_attribute_like_date.strftime('%Y-%W')
  end
end
```

This will give you a grouped list in the format of YYYY-WW

Answer (score 2):

Check out the has_activity plugin.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer.  Looks like has_activity is mysql only.  My production host is postgresql.

Answer (score 2):

Check out the group date gem

https://github.com/ankane/groupdate

it has recent commits, works with postgresql, integrates easily with chart kick for fast charting, and works with time zones!!

Comment: GroupDate is only working with UTC, so if you are using another timezone in your database, consider alternatives.