# Group records by both month and year in Rails

Tags: mysql, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, group-by

I'm on Ruby 1.9.2, Rails 3.0.x and I use MySQL DB. I have a Messages Model, where one can post new messages every day.

I have an index action where I want to display these messages grouped by both month and year. This basically is used to filter messages.

My query looks like this:-

```
@active_msgs = Messages.where('expiry > ?', Time.now).order('created_at DESC')
```

I used the group_by function in Rails, after referring to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/902974/grouping-by-week-month-etc-activerecord)

My Group By Query is:-

```
@msgs_by_month = @active_msgs.all.group_by {|u| u.created_at.month }
```

I was returned a Hash called @msgs_by_month. This helped me group the messages by month, but  I need to taken into account the year, **to form a unique key** , as it would help me differentiate between for e.g., Sept 2011 and Sept 2012.

My current key only is of type Hash[Month] ( e.g. Hash[9] => for month of September, I can display all appropriate values ). How can i get a unique key of type month, year which I can easily loop though to display all records grouped by Month and Year of creation.

Thank you

**EDIT**:-

I'm guessing one way to do this, is to make use the `created_at.to_date` api, provided [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Time.html)
. I only wonder, how I can **strip out the day** from `created_at.to_date` to get a **unique** month and year **combination key** which could **work with the group_by function**.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL Query GROUP BY day / month / year](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/508791/mysql-query-group-by-day-month-year)

Comment: Nah, not duplicate. the q you're referring to is only MYSQL-related where this q is a rails + mysql..

Answer (score 37, accepted):

In SQL:

```
select * from messages group by year(created_at), month(created_at);
```

In Rails:

```
Message.all.group_by { |m| m.created_at.beginning_of_month }
```

Comment: Thanks dude.. :). It works when I enter the where clause also into the query.. Just for info of all..

Comment: DownVote because it selects all record for a month avoiding the year. So Data of Dec 2017 & Dec 2018 falls under same HASH

Comment: This solution should never be used. as @HuzaifaSaifuddin mentioned, this is selecting all records -- so it loads the entire messages table into memory and then uses the group_by method on the returned Object. This will fail to scale.

Comment: @JohnHinnegan do you have any idea how to group_by without loading all the records in memory while getting a hash on result like group_by method does?

Comment: @medBouzid look at the other answers which, IMHO, are better. You want to use the `group` method which translates into a SQL group. Other answers have working solutions. For a Rails-specific solution, the answer from @Dorian below will produce approximately the same SQL as the answer suggested here.

Comment: Like others said, this will pull all messages into memory which scales very badly

Answer (score 3):

Use Group Date.

It supports time zones, so if you ever need to - the code will easily evolve.

https://github.com/ankane/groupdate

Answer (score 3):

```
Message.select("date_trunc('month', created_at) as month").group("month")
```

Answer (score 1):

To group by year and by month (e.g. not having december 2020 with december 2021):

```rb
Message.group("date_trunc('year', created_at), date_trunc('month', created_at)")
```

Tested on PostgreSQL

Answer (score -1):

```
ModelName.all.group_by { |m| m.created_at.month }
```

This will work, however month will be returned as the index.
Ex. Nov would refer to 11